# Multiple listeners in web.xml?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-listeners

How do I specify multiple listener classes in web.xml? I tried searching the web without luck.

I tried the following, but it seems that it doesn't work:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.obliquid.web.StartAndStop
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is the correct syntax. What "didn't work"? It's not this bit, unless perhaps you mean there's an XML parsing error because it's in the wrong place in the doc.

EDIT: the 'right' place if I recall correctly is before `<servlet>` but I am not sure if the latest XSD schemas do restrict that. You would get a clear parsing error if this was the problem.

Comment: yes, maybe is something else, but you mentioned it could be in the wrong place in web.xml? i placed it near the top, where should i put it?

Comment: @Nicolae, actually it is an answer because my question is "How do I specify multiple listener classes in web.xml?". As Sean said, my problem could be elsewhere, but also answers my question about the syntax.

Comment: @Nicolae The question was how to specify multiple listeners, and that's what was answered -- you do it as shown. It is an answer.

Comment: Now that I've removed this doubt about the syntax, I've posted another question with the problem I'm facing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723740/how-do-i-debug-a-no-mapping-found-for-http-request