# How do I debug a "No Mapping found for HTTP Request"?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm trying to map a Controller with Spring 3.0 without success. I've the following error:

2011-07-17 20:01:16,536 [http-8080-exec-5] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sherd/cp/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cp'

How I debug this error? I've set the log to INFO and saw:

2011-07-17 20:10:28,402 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/cp/index] onto handler 'index'
2011-07-17 20:10:28,402 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/cp/index.*] onto handler 'index'
2011-07-17 20:10:28,402 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/cp/index/] onto handler 'index'

However, I get the WARN shown above when trying to load the page.

The relevant part of WEB-INF/web.xml is the following:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/cp-beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've WEB-INF/cp-servlet.xml with the following content:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="org.obliquid.sherd.web.cp"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
</beans>
```

And WEB-INF/cp-beans.xml is basically empty for now:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
</beans>
```

I've defined the class Index in the package org.obliquid.sherd.web.cp

```
package org.obliquid.sherd.web.cp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Spring MVC controller for /cp/index
 * 
 * @author stivlo
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cp/index")
public class Index {

    @RequestMapping
    public String show() {
        return "cp/index"; //view 
    }

}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work with the following changes:

```
@Controller
public class Index {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String show() {
        return "index"; //view 
    }

}
```

Notice that I've removed the /cp prefix in @RequestMapping and in the logical view name returned. Also, in cp-servlet.xml I've added the following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/cp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I can't test, but try to change this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

RequestMapping annotation has `/cp` so it should be omitted in `servlet-mapping`.

Comment: Hi Sangdol, thank you for the suggestion. The reason why I've a prefix is because I also have other servlet mappings that I would like to migrate slowly. Anyway, for testing I tried "/*" url-pattern and also "/", but I've still the same WARN.